# Creating a drop down date selection in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I've been asked to create a start and end date parameter for a report but they don't want the calendar selection. They would like a drop-down list of dates from the invoice documents. I have this statement in my stored procedure for filtering dates.

> CONVERT(DATE,Invoice.Date) >= @StartDate
>     CONVERT(DATE,Invoice.Date)
>   <= @EndDate

I'm not sure how to approach creating a text parameter for dates.

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate dataset with all the invoice dates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Invoice.Date, 101) AS INVOICE_DATE
FROM Invoice
ORDER BY Invoice.Date DESC
```

For the parameters' Available Values, use **Get Values from a Query** and use the dataset you create above and set the Value and Label fields to the INVOICE_DATE field.

You can also set the Default Values to the same dataset/field to the same so it defaults to the last INVOICE_DATE.